# WSO2, not allowed subscribers to create application

Tags: wso2, subscriber

I'm a newer in wso2 and having some confusions regarding subscribers who log into the developer portal for subscribe to APIs. In fact,i created a user with the role internal\subscriber and internal\selfsignup and after logging in with this user, I expected that he could only see the APIs created and subscribed to them with the applications created in the /publisher page, but it seems that this user has the possibility to create these own applications and I do not see how to withdraw these privileges. I want it to use also the apps created in /publisher.
Best regards

Answer (score 0):

The question is a little confusing. Please find the basic ideas of API visibility and API subscription availability below.

- You can create applications in the devportal or store portal
- You can create APIs in the publisher portal

In general, when you create an API in the publisher portal and publish it without any role visibility restrictions, anyone can view those APIs. To view these publicly available APIs in devportal, you don't even have to log in to the devportal. This is can be viewed in anonymous mode.

In case if you have restricted the API visibility in devportal based on roles, then only the users with the allowed roles can view those APIs.

Similar to API visibility, you also can control the API subscription in the devportal. The subscription availability option will only be displayed if there are tenants in your environment.

Please refer to the [official document](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/design-api/advanced-topics/control-api-visibility-and-subscription-availability-in-developer-portal/) for more details on this topic.